# How to extract mov_mean, mov_var, scale and shift from tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm and insert later manually into the test_feed?

Tags: tensorflow

Playing around with Batch-norm, I like to extract `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`, scale and shift arrays from [tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm) (which are collected over the training) and store it in a separate list.

After that I like to use all 4 parameter in my pretrained test model which I restore by my own method (by pickle, so no .ckpt file).

Is it feasible to extract all these values from `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` and feed it manually back into the test model?

So far I looked into:

`update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS) with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops): train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)`

But I am not sure whether these these values are mov_mean and mov_var or scale and shift? In any case two parameters are still missing.

Any suggestions? (If not, I go for manual implementation)

Comment: How about searching for all variables in `tf.global_variables()`? Or before training, give a collection to `variables_collections` then all bn variables will be added to this collection.

Comment: do you have link for a tutorial, how to do that?

Comment: Maybe begin with `for v in tf.global_variables(): print v.name` and check whether the values you want to extract are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to do it:

(1) specific solution: get all 4 variables from variables_collections (u need to pass a list of a string!):

```
bnorm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(predicted_outputs,center=True,scale=True,
        is_training=True, updates_collections=tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS,variables_collections=['vars2'], outputs_collections='vars', decay=0.999, zero_debias_moving_mean=False)
```

then init session and print out:

```
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print("variables_collections")
print("mov_mean, mov_var,beta, gamma")
all_vars = tf.get_collection('vars2')
all_vars4 = session.run(all_vars,feed_dict=feedvalid)
print(len(all_vars4))
print(all_vars4[0])
print(all_vars4[1])
print(all_vars4[2])
print(all_vars4[3])
```

(2) general solution: use variable_scope (this always works for all type of functions):

```
with tf.variable_scope("Bnorm"):
        bnorm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(predicted_outputs,center=True,scale=True,
        is_training=True, decay=0.999, zero_debias_moving_mean=False)
```

and init session first and print out like above:

```
print("Global: tf.GraphKeys")
print("mov_mean, mov_var,beta, gamma")
all_vars10 = tf.get_collection(key=tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="Bnorm")
all_vars11 = session.run(all_vars10,feed_dict=feedvalid)
print(len(all_vars11))
print(all_vars11)
```

**Update: assign values (from training) for testing (inference)**

```
beta_ass = all_vars10[0].assign(np.ones(all_vars10[0].shape) * 7) #get the tf.variable beta and assign a 7 to it
print("assigned: beta with 7")
print (session.run(beta_ass)) #sess.run is needed to really assign values to matrices!!
```

Now do one of the solutions above and check that the value is really assigned. Additionally set `is_training=False` to keep all values konstant for Testing.